# Rails: Query ActiveRecord by month and year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails project there is a search page that contains a drop-down with date range values separated by (-). The options of drop-down are like:

```
Jan,2014 - March,2014
April,2014 - Jun,2014
....
Oct,2014 - Dec,2014
```

User can select one of these date ranges and only those records will be shown that fall in selected date range. The field to filter by is `start_date` with is a timestamp field.

So I want something like this:

```
filter = params[:filter].split("-") 
@posts = Post.where(start_date: filter[0]..filter[1])
```

But in params I only get month and year. How can I parse these values so that the above query works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hey you can try to parse string to date using [Date.strptime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strptime/class)

```
filter = params[:filter].split(" - ")
```

Convert string to date using `strptime`

```
st_date = Date.strptime(filter[0],"%B,%Y")
end_date = Date.strptime(filter[1],"%B,%Y")
```

Create daterange as beginning of first month to end of second month

```
date_range = st_date.beginning_of_month..end_date.end_of_month

@posts = Post.where(:start_date =>  date_range)
```

Comment: Thanks. The end_date was getting error so I split it by (" - ") instead of ("-")

Comment: Yes, it adjusted thanks. There were extra spaces. Thanks

Comment: Please update your answer to use filter[1] in end_date. And also while calculating date_rang do we need beginning_of_month and end_of_month again ?